# How to aggregate with match, group and sort by one field

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB. this is my document. collection name is test

```
{"group_id":"111","image":"x1.jpg",create_time:129}
{"group_id":"111","image":"x2.jpg",create_time:94}
{"group_id":"222","image":"x3.jpg",create_time:129}
{"group_id":"222","image":"x4.jpg",create_time:101}
```

An example for an expected output

```
{"group_id":"111","count":2,"image":["x1.jpg","x2.jpg"]}
{"group_id":"222","count":2,"image":["x3.jpg","x4.jpg"]}
```

Then I try

```
db.test.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":{"group_id":"$group_id"},"count":{"$sum":1},"image":{"$push":"$image"}}},{"$sort":{"count":1}}],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

But I want get the result that image is sorted by create_time. like this:

```
{"group_id":"111","count":2,"image":["x2.jpg","x1.jpg"]}
{"group_id":"222","count":2,"image":["x4.jpg","x3.jpg"]}
```

Anyone can guide me for the right combination of group by and sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one more sort

> {'$sort' : {"group_id" : 1,"image" : 1}}

in the beginning of aggregate pipe

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {'$sort' : {"group_id" : 1,"image" : 1}},
    {"$group":{"_id":{"group_id":"$group_id"},"count":{"$sum":1},"image":{"$push":"$image"}}},
    {"$sort":{"count":1}}],
{allowDiskUse:true})
```

Hope you will get expected result

Comment: {"$sort":{"group_id":1,"create_time":1}}  it's wil be ok

Comment: should be sort on `create_time` instead of `image`, `{'$sort' : {"group_id" : 1,"create_time" : 1}}`